# creating an expandable area in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to CSS and Javascript. I want to create a specific area (I use the `div` tag) in the page where once a link is clicked within, the area will expand and an additional content would be displayed. I managed to create a code which does the job only partially: the new content is displayed after the click but this content is not displayed within the area border. In few words the area is not expanded, only a new content is displayed...any suggestion?

Comment: are you using jquery or native javascript?

Comment: One suggestion: post the code you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

I really like this jQuery accordion method:

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kbZDv/1/

It's easy to use, style and looks good.

All you need to do is include the latest version of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
```

Here is the **HTML** markup:

```
<p class="trigger"><a href="#">Click here to expand and reveal more information</a></p>
<div class="toggle_container">
   <div class="block">
        <p>Content goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The basic (yet to be styled) **CSS**:

```
p.trigger{
    margin-bottom:7px;
    margin-top:-5px;
}

.toggle_container{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.toggle_container p{
    margin:0px;
}

.toggle_container{
    background:#f0f0f0;
    clear: both;
    font-size:100%;
}
```

And the all important **jQuery** to make it work:

```
$(".toggle_container").hide();

    $("p.trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("normal");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jquery plugin like div expand?
http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/div-expand

or perhaps a jquery exander plugin
http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html